# Does the day night cycle in Minecraft keep going when browsing the menu in single player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does the game keep going while in the menu in single player?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. the day night cycle is ongoing

Comment: Not sure why you answered your own question on this one. If you're on a single player world and you open the escape menu, the embedded server stops along with your client, meaning the day/night cycle also stops. This is changed by opening to LAN or joining a multiplayer server, as the server is no longer in sync with one client. Opening an inventory is not the same as the escape menu, and does not pause the server when playing on single player